# pass sqlite options through sqlite3 ruby gem

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rubygems

```
class Database
  include Cinch::Plugin

  match /select .* from gears where .* like .*/i

  def execute(m)
    db = SQLite3::Database.new( "development.sqlite3")
    m.reply db.execute("#{m.message}")
end
end
```

In sqlite you are able to run the `.mode line` option to have your returned records displayed on a per line basis. You can also have an init file and pass the `-init file` parameter different configs set, one of which could be the `.mode line`. I would like to find a way to either pass the `-line` or `-init file` parameters when opening my database through the sqlite gem.

Comment: You will need to a bit more specific about your intentions as right now you have not even shown a call to execute at all so we have no idea what you are trying to accomplish. If this is a simple seed then you should be able to script this fairly easily. The [Docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/luislavena/sqlite3-ruby/SQLite3/Database) show that you can execute within the `new` method did you look at that? Also I am assuming m  is a Cinch::Bot? But why and are you sure you are using it correctly?

Comment: Yes the matched statement gets passed into the db.execute field which then returns the records from the db. What am trying to do is format that records returned to be in a different style. In sqlite you can set it to `.mode line` and it will change the output to one data value per line. I would like to have this be the way that the data is returned in irc as well. Thus I am looking as to how to format the data returned either through the sqlite gem functions or a way to pass `-line` to the start of my db instance that is started by sqlite3 gem.

Comment: Or a way to pass the `-init file` parameter when I open the `SQLite3::Database.new( "development.sqlite3")` is another option that would work if there is a way of doing this.

Comment: in that case make this part of your question since it was in no way stated. Also I still lack for an understanding as to what you hope to accomplish since execute will create a new DB every time? Shouldn't you just create the DB and then use `open` or at least make sure you are removing the file before trying to create a new one? I have no idea what you hope to accomplish with match since this has no implications in execute.

Comment: My match parameter takes takes a matching regex expression and inputs it into the database which then returns the results of the sql query to the irc channel. This part is already functional I am just trying to format the output in a more readable syntax. It is basically a irc front end to query a database.

Comment: what output are you expecting because execute returns an `Array` something as simple as `db.execute(...).join('\n')` would create a string with new lines. Also it might make more sense to accept a statement and bind variables so that SQLite can clean them for you.

Comment: something like this would be ideal.... `id = 6
        RU = 40
   Devname = arpa-ops (primary)
   Devtype = Cisco 4948
       Lab = Primary
  Swportib = 
   Swport1 = 
   Swport2 = 
   Swport3 = 
      IBip = 
      Nic1 = 192.168.0.254
      Nic2 = 
      Nic3 = 
   Nic1mac = 
   Nic2mac = 
   Nic3mac = 
     IBmac = 
      Psu1 = ST30
      Psu2 = ST33
        SN = 
created_at = 2015-05-19 14:23:15.958470
updated_at = 2015-05-19 14:23:15.958470` with each being on there own lines.